# ProtoBuf type casting issue

Tags: .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I use ProtoBuf to serialize class. Unfortunately Serializer.Deserialize method gives error "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: System.Object". Any hint how to solve this.

```
private void WriteToFile( string siteID, object objectTemp, stringfileSystemPath)
        {
            var type = objectTemp.GetType();
using (var file = File.Create(fileSystemPath))
                {
                    Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(file, objectTemp);
                }
        }

private object ReadFromFile( string siteID, object objectTemp, stringfileSystemPath)
        {
            Type type = objectTemp.GetType();   
            object objectTemp2=null;
                using (var file = File.OpenRead(fileSystemPath))
                {
                    objectTemp2 = Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(type, file);
                }
                return objectTemp2;
            }
        }
```

I am using protobuf.Net v2 beta with .Net 3.5

Comment: What is objectTemp when you are calling ReadFromFile? That is the key here, since that is where you are getting `type` from. Personally, since you aren't merging, I'd just pass a `Type` to this method, not an object. For it to be talking about `object` you must currently be assign it a `new object()` - so indeed, it can't extrapolate that you want a `Customer` (or whatever) from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize` wants to be provided a protobuf-generated type. (you are giving it the type of `System.Object`. It doesn't know what to do with that).

Look at the C# code generated by protoc, and specify a `typeof()` of the class you are trying to read from file.

Or put another way, if `WriteToFile` is succeeding, then use the type of objectTemp.  The type that went in to the file is the type that needs to come out of the file.

Comment: Thanks SethCall. I am not sure I understand this statement "look at the C# code generated by protoc, and specify a typeof() of the class you are trying to read from file.". I don't want to change the "object" parameter to the "actual type" in the "WriteToFile" method since I would have to create multiple methods for different types. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let's put it this way; your signature should say:
private object ReadFromFile( string siteID, Type objectType, string fileSystemPath), where the Type should be the same type of object that went into the file initially.

Comment: Your answer is correct - the Type does need to be meaningful; however, re any confusion over the middle line: protobuf-net can work with or without code-generation, and when it *does* use code-generation it uses "protogen", which uses "protoc" internally - so the use of "protoc" is hidden slightly.